# Using TFS in Visual Studio automatically adds excluded items to work in progress sometimes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

This problem really annoys me and I don't know what's it that I'm doing wrong.

I make a lot of local changes in my Visual Studio solution that should remain local and never checked in to the remote TFS repository. So I exclude these changes. Now when I am working on a work item in TFS, I sometimes find that all the excluded items have automatically been added to the Work in Progress area...and this ends up messing with my work. When it's time to check in, I have to individually exclude the files yet again else everything would get checked in.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you exclude a change you are doing just that, excluding the change, not excluding the file. To exclude future modifications of the file from being checked-in select the file in the solution explorer and then choose `File` -> `Source Control` -> `Advanced` -> `Exclude <file name> from Source Control` like this:

[image: excluding file from Source Control]